# ng-bootstrap NgbTypeahead How to react on select?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-typeahead, ng-bootstrap

Using the typeahead control allows a user to select a term from a list ([Documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead), [plnkr](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/typeahead/demos/http/plnkr.html)).

How can I react on a selection? I managed to react on enter by adding a (keyup.enter) event to the input then call another method on my component, but I cannot seem to get an event that fires on mouse-selection in the typeahead-popup.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `selectItem` output (event) that is fired when a user does item selection (regardless of the selection method). The `selectItem` output is part of the [official typeahead documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api)

Comment: if you can post an example that would be very helpfull, new to typeahead :)

Comment: @IdoBleicher duplicate question with example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43008142/3165014