# NgbTypeahead selectItem get clicked item ngBootstrap angular2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-typeahead, ng-bootstrap

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994334/1591992), it was explained to me to use selectItem to get the select event.

But at this point, the model I bound to the text box is still the original text the user typed, not the select item.

I use

```
(selectItem)="search(model)"
```

to get the event, and in TS

```
search(model) { 
this._service.search(model).subscribe(
  results => this.results = results,
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

}

but as mentioned above, that calls my backend with the user-typed text, not the full text of the selected item of the typeahead.

My backend logs

```
2017/03/24 20:44:14 /api/typeahead/ok
2017/03/24 20:44:14 /api/search/ok
```

where the second should be /api/search/$actualSelectedItem.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should be using `$event` to get the selected Items as below

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (selectItem)="selectedItem($event)" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultFormatter]="formatter" />
<hr>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
clicked item {{clickedItem}}
```

Your method should be as

```
selectedItem(item){
    this.clickedItem=item.item;
    console.log(item);
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/BX6Vv3k4ei0O3m2F5Kpn?p=preview)**

Comment: It seems so easy now. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone needs it, here's some docs: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api#NgbTypeahead