# angular2 input autocomplete ngmodel value not change?

Tags: angular

```
<input #searchBox id="search-box" [(ngModel)]="search_name" 
      (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)"> {{search_name}}
```

1st key:-
[image]
2nd key:-
[image]

Click on autocomplete

**  ngmodel value not change?**

Comment: refer this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007815/ngbtypeahead-selectitem-get-clicked-item-ngbootstrap-angular2/43008142#43008142)

Comment: This is the browser autocomplete