# ngbtypeAhead demo for Wikipedia search - broken in that selectItem event wont reliably fire

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

See url: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead

the Wikipedia search demo shows the error.

If you click on a retrieved search item in the drop down, sometimes the selectItem gets fired and some times it does not.  If it does, it takes lik 10 seconds.

Can someone look at the demo and see what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NgbTypeahead selectItem get clicked item ngBootstrap angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007815/ngbtypeahead-selectitem-get-clicked-item-ngbootstrap-angular2)

Comment: i can upload a video showing the issue if you want.

Comment: I looked at the ngSource and it appears that: 1. Mouse click is not handled when user clicks on a search result item row (;  and 2.  NgbTypeahead.prototype.handleKeyDown = function (event) {
        if (!this.isPopupOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        if (Key[toString(event.which)]) {

            switch (event.which) {
                case Key.ArrowDown:     and this code is NOT reliably fired for some reason <--------

Comment: I see the issue.  If you click on the blue row (not on the text in the row) it works great.  If yo click on the text, the click is NEVER detected.   Can you fix this ASAP?  So much thanks.

Comment: can someone look into this bug please?