# NgbTypeahead - event to detect when selectItem is blanked out after selection ngBootstrap angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43008142/178890) I was able to solve my initial problem in capturing the selected item in a ngTypeahead input item.

But my issue now is if the user blanks out the field, is there an event or method of capturing that.  [aravind's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858469/aravind) Plunker in his answer show's the problem I'm looking a solution for.  If you type a state in and then remove it the "clicked item" is not changed or removed.  I need to capture when the field has change to a value not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running into this. For anyone who wants to know my workaround, add `(change)=noItemSelected($event)` to the ngbTypeahead input field. The `(change)` event fires before the `(selectedItem)` event does.

Really awful workaround, but I agree this is something that needs to be fixed with ngbTypeahead.